# How to use on scroll with render function in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, scroll, render

I'm trying to add a scroll watcher inside a render function. While the click is supported, I haven't found anything for the scroll. Has anyone faced the same issue and over passed it?

I've tried to use it with the args "on" and "nativeOn" and none of them work.

```
let h = createElement('div', {
    'class': 'container'
}, [
   createElement('div', {
       class': 'main',
       nativeOn: {
           scroll: () => {
               console.log('scrollllling')
           }
       }
   }, [ 
          createElement(draggable, {
              props: {
                  element: 'div',
                  class: 'someClass',
                  options: this.options,
                  list: this.list
              }
          }, [allChildren]),
          createElement(EditTooltip)
      ])
  ])
return h
```

I finally bypassed it with a window.document.body.onscroll in mounted but i hope there is a cleaner solution..?

Comment: have you checked out custom directives? https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/creating-custom-scroll-directives.html

Comment: Yes, thank you ! But i still haven't figured out how to call the directive with the render ! Do you know how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
createElement('div', {
       class': 'main',
       on: {
           scroll: this.someMethod
       }
},
```

[documents render functions](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help] center.